# Click through images using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a database containing slides, named "df_slides". Now I would like to display the individual silde, and when I click on the "next" button is should show the next slide in the database.  The slides are stored in base64 format.

This is what I have done so far:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import base64
import pandas as pd

i = 0
def load_next_img():
    global pil_image, tk_image, i

    i = i+1
    base64string = df_slides["Slide_Image"][i]
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(base64string)
    pil_image =  Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
    panel = tkinter.Label(root, image = tk_image)
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
    label['image'] = tk_image


root = tkinter.Tk()
label = tkinter.Label(root)
label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
nextbutton = tkinter.Button(text="next", command=load_next_img)

nextbutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I just started with tkinter and I am having some difficulties. In essence, the program works, but when I open it I have some difficulties:

1. It opens but only shows the "next" buttom

[image]

2. I then click on "next" and then it shows two images

[image]
... then when I continue to click on "next" it's fine and it shows only one image at a time

### Edit

If I try:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import base64
import pandas as pd

i = 0
def load_next_img():
    global pil_image, tk_image, i

    i = i+1
    base64string = df_slides["Slide_Image"][i]
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(base64string)
    pil_image =  Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
    label['image'] = tk_image


root = tkinter.Tk()
label = tkinter.Label(root,image = tk_image)
label.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
nextbutton = tkinter.Button(text="next", command=load_next_img)

nextbutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I get the error:

> NameError: name 'tk_image' is not defined

Comment: You are creating a new `Label` widget named `panel` every time you click next. Use your existing `label` instead.

Comment: @HenryYik Thanks for your comment. How can I do that ? (sorry if this is trivial)

Comment: Remove `image = tk_image` in your initial setup of `label`. You only need to change it when `load_next_img` is called.

Comment: @HenryYik Great ! Thanks a lot ! Do you also know, how to initialize it with the first slide ?

Comment: do you mean you want to show the first image right at the start of program? If so just call `load_next_img()`. before mainloop.